# Calling Code-behind method from JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to call a code behind method from JavaScript.  Here is the scenario: the user will see messagebox in which he/she can select Yes or No.  If user selects Yes from the messagebox i want to call the Delete method in code behind else i want to call the Insert method.
here is JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function Func() {
            var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
            if (result) {
                //click ok button
                //Call the Delete Method
            }
            else {
                //click cancel button
                //Call the Insert method
            }
        }
</script>
```

here is how my code-behind look like:

```
protected void Delete()
{
  //delete code here
}
protected void Insert()
{
  //insert code here
}
```

Comment: Look up "WebMethod", "Ajax" or "ASP.NET WebAPI" on Google. I'll have a duplicate link shortly.

Comment: If you're using a databound control (e.g., `ListView` or `GridView`) that provides its own Delete button fully wired up, you can hook in a validation javascript. Otherwise, you're tasked with writing up the entire end-to-end client->server conversation yourself.